# An API call return the body, but can't reach the properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mapbox

I'm currently using the [Mapbox geocoding API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/) and I found a strange bug.

```
const geocode = async (address, callback) => {
    const url = `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${address}.json?access_token=token&limit=1`
    try {
        const req = await got(url, { responseType: 'json' })
        console.log(req.body) //I get the data
        console.log(req.body.type) //I get undefined
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        callback(undefined, 'Can\'t reach the geocoding API')
    }
}
```

An example of the result of this API :

```
    {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "query": [
        "boston"
        ],
        "features": [
        {
        "id": "place.9391334652012190",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
        "place"
        ],
        "relevance": 1,
        "properties": {
        "wikidata": "Q100"
        },
        "text": "Boston",
        "place_name": "Boston, Massachusetts, United States",
        "bbox": [
        -71.1255750165112,
        42.3196059806256,
        -70.9860500028801,
        42.3974009328397
        ],
        "center": [
        -71.0596,
        42.3605
        ],
        "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
        -71.0596,
        42.3605
        ]
        },
        "context": [
        {
        "id": "region.8307399429561540",
        "wikidata": "Q771",
        "short_code": "US-MA",
        "text": "Massachusetts"
        },
        {
        "id": "country.19678805456372290",
        "wikidata": "Q30",
        "short_code": "us",
        "text": "United States"
        }
        ]
        }
        ],
        "attribution": "NOTICE: © 2021 Mapbox and its suppliers. All rights reserved. Use of this data is subject to the Mapbox Terms of Service (https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/). This response and the information it contains may not be retained. POI(s) provided by Foursquare."
}
```

Actually when I'm call the req.body, the API give me all the data.

But when I want to access to one specific value, like type, for this example, it returned undefined, and I don't understand why ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is `got`? Hard to say without knowing what that is, but I would guess that your response is still a string and hasn't been run through `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Yes, it's got, I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/go), your `response.body` for a successful request will look like

```
{
  status: 'success',
  data: <your-response-body-here>
}
```

So in order to access the response payload you'd need to do:

```
 const response = await got(url, { responseType: 'json' })
 console.log(response.body.data);
```

Note that you can simplify this by passing the `resolveBodyOnly` option. `response` will then hold the response payload directly:

```
const response = await got(url, { responseType: 'json', resolveBodyOnly: true })
console.log(response.data);
```